# Infinite loop when using size_t in a count down for loop

Tags: c, loops, infinite-loop, size-t

So I'm using `size_t` instead of `int` in any indexing for loop to prevent negative indices. But when counting down, this leads to an overflow:

```
for (size_t i = 10; i >= 0; --i) {
    // Do something, f.ex. array[i] = i
}
```

What would be a nice way to prevent this?

- Using `int` instead?
- Using i == 0 as the termination condition? (This would however not work if I need the 0)

I'd appreciate any feedback!

Comment: It is not technically an overflow because `size_t` is an unsigned type, but it is definitely an infinite loop since the termination condition is always true.

Answer (score 7):

```
for (size_t i = 11; i-- > 0; ) {
    // Do something, f.ex. array[i] = i
}
```

---

Note: The question starts the loop with value=10(which is strange, but not impossible). I start with 11, but the first time the loop body is enterered, it has already been decremented to 10.

Comment: Yes. The quetion starts the loop with value=10(which is strange, but not impossible). I start with 11, but the first time the loop *body* is enterered, it has already been decremented,

Answer (score 7):

```
for (size_t i = 10; i <= 10; --i) // do something
```

When overflow do happens, it will round to the largest integer and thus the condition will fail.

Comment: @Stargateur Yes. I just copy and added the `i <= 10` part. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Novel way of controlling looping: UV, yet it _looks_ counter-intuitive.

Comment: When I was a wee nipper I used to do it this way, but got reprimanded by my professor.

Comment: I would not recommend anyone to do what showed here. It's probalythe solution with the minimal change to OP's code. But either use a signed counter or rewrite the loop to use increments are much cleaner

Answer (score 5):

It is not technically an overflow because `size_t` is an unsigned type, but it is definitely an infinite loop since the termination condition is always true.

Unsigned integers *wrap around* when decremented at `0`.  Note that your loop will run `11` times before the wrap around occurs, not `10`.

You must check for the condition before decrementing the index. Starting the enumeration with an initial value one more than the maximum valid index improves visual consistency and simplifies the test.

Here is a corrected version where you can see that the initial value for `i` is the number of elements of the array:

```
int array[11];
for (size_t i = 11; i-- > 0; ) {
    // Do something, f.ex. array[i] = i
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic, though not to everyone's taste way, is to use the slide operator:

```
for (size_t i = 10 + 1; i--> 0; )
```

It isn't really an operator but that's what it has become known as over the years.

Comment: I personally call it the downto operator.

Answer (score 3):

`size_t i = 10; i >= 0;` is never false as `size_t` is some unsigned type and all values are greater than or equal to zero.

> ... `size_t` which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator; ...
> C11 §7.19 2

**Enable all warnings**

A *good* compiler with warnings enabled would have warned about this.
Hopefully, that infinite loop would never had occurred as an investigation to the warning would have first rectified the problem.

---

Best alternative depends on coding goals

Good code avoids magic numbers like this naked 10.  Better if code derived that.  In this simple case, it should have been 11.

```
#define A_SIZE 11
int array[A_SIZE];
...
for (size_t i = A_SIZE; i-- > 0; ) {
    // Do something, f.ex. array[i] = i
}
```

OTOH, code may have had `break` conditions in the loop and needs `i` in later code to indicate `array[]` usages

```
size_t i = A_SIZE;
while (i > 0) {
  if (...) break; 
  i--;
  // Do something, f.ex. array[i] = i
  if (...) break; 
}
// Do something with i
```

Code may have a *contract requirement* to use a `10` in various places.

```
// Contract says loop must handle indexes 0 to N, inclusive
#define N 10
int array[N + 1];

for (size_t i = N; i + 1 > 0; i--) {
  // Do something, f.ex. array[i] = i
}
```

Good optimizing compilers will not perform a `+1` on each `i + 1 > 0`, but create equivalent efficient code.

Code is a fashion that best conveys the overall meaning of the code.

Comment: Amazing! I never thought of `i + 1 > 0` to test for wrap around.  It is equivalent to `i != SIZE_MAX`, less ugly but arguably more intriguing as it begs for simplification.  One case is not covered: it does not work for `N = SIZE_MAX`, which is rather rare on modern systems, but was not uncommon in the days of 16-bit protected mode.  You could also use `i != -1`, which has the same shortcoming.

Comment: Looks nice indeed. I guess in practice this would be error prone to off by one's since you could easily forget to add 1. Using SIZE_MAX is not that much more counterintuitive than `i <= n; --i` or `i-- > 0;`, all of them anticipate the wrap around.

Answer (score 2):

A simplest way is to increase the upper value. For example

```
const size_t N = 10;

for (size_t i = N + 1; i != 0; --i) {
    // Do something, f.ex. array[i-1] = i-1
}
```

or

```
const size_t N = 10;

for (size_t i = N + 1; i-- != 0; ) {
    // Do something, f.ex. array[i] = i
}
```

In general case when i can be equal to the maximum value stored in an object of the type `size_t` you can use the following trick

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    for (size_t i = N, j = N; !( i == 0 && j == -1 ); j--)
    {
        i = j;
        printf( "%zu ", i );
    }

    printf( "\n" );
}
```

Otherwise you can use do-while loop. It is more suitable in this case. For example

```
size_t i = N;

do
{
    printf( "%zu ", i );
} while ( i-- != 0 );
```

Comment: Okay, you win (by 4 seconds!)

Comment: @AdHominem  Why can not you use 0? The initiall value of the loop 0 + 1. So you can use 0.

Comment: I don't believe there is anything numerically wrong with this answer. And it's comprehensive. Plus one.